# Regex to match only long integers in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, long-integer

I need to create a regex to validate **long integer** inputs and ensure they are **long integer positive values**. This means that the valid range should be between `0` and `9223372036854775807`

There is a way to create the regex without the need to manually add all the valid digits through ranges (i.e `\d{0,18} | [1-8]\d{0,18} | 9[0-1]\d{0,17} | 92[0-1]\d{0,16} ...`)?

Comment: Regex cannot tell you if a number is in a range. Only that the characters match a pattern.

Comment: No, there is not. This is normally not what regex are used for. You'd normally extract a likely portion (e.g. `\d+`), then check by other means. If you do want to use regex alone, what you posted is pretty much exactly how it would go (though you could optimise it, for example by creating a proper trie, e.g. collapsing the `9` cases: `9(?:[01]\d{,17}|2(?:...))`)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know the purpose of regex, but maybe there was some regex builder doing the work without having to code it myself

Comment: Just making you aware of regex's limitations.

Comment: There is tons: search for "numeric range regex generator". Or use [to-regex-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-regex-range) library.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in the comment, what you have is (close to) the best way to do it just with regex. This is usually not handled just by regex. Here is the simplest way to do it:

```js
function validateLongInt(str) {
  return str.match(/^\d+$/) && BigInt(str) <= 9223372036854775807n;
}

console.log(validateLongInt("0"))  // truthy
console.log(validateLongInt("1"))  // truthy
console.log(validateLongInt("9223372036854775807"))  // truthy
console.log(validateLongInt("-1")) // falsy
console.log(validateLongInt("9223372036854775808"))  // falsy
console.log(validateLongInt("A"))  // falsy
console.log(validateLongInt(""))   // falsy
```

Note that you cannot do this comparison with regular JavaScript numbers (or at least, not naively), since you are interested in numbers that are outside the safe integer range:

```js
const max = 9223372036854775807;
console.log(max + 1 > max); // false?!?
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a pure regex solution, but in addition to validating the it "looks" like it's within range with regex, you can iterate over each index of the string and compare its value with the target string.

```js
const MAX_VALUE = "9223372036854775807";
const lengthCheck = new RegExp(`^\\d{1,${MAX_VALUE.length}}$`);

function validateLongPositiveInteger(value) {
  if (!lengthCheck.test(value)) {
    return false;
  }

  if (value.length < MAX_VALUE.length) {
    return true;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE.length; i++) {
    if (value[i] > MAX_VALUE[i]) {
      return false;
    }
    if (value[i] < MAX_VALUE[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: According to this code, `"93"` does not represent a valid long integer.

Comment: Ah thanks, updated with additional length check. It should not compare digits if the input string is shorter than the max value's length.

Answer (score 0):

If the reg exp is not a hard requirement then there is another way fo doing the validation:

```js
const isValidPositiveLongNumber = (input: string | number | undefined, maxValue = 9223372036854775807): boolean => {

  if (input === undefined || input === null) {
    return false;  
  }
  const parsed = parseInt(input);
  if (isNaN(parsed)) {
    return false;
  }

  return parsed >= 0 && parsed <= maxValue;
}

console.log(isValidPositiveLongNumber("-6789"));
console.log(isValidPositiveLongNumber("12423554"));
```

Comment: This does not work: `"9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807"` will  produce `true`, but should return `false` according to OP's requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I intended it without space, but even with space it demonstrates a problem.

Comment: Why don't you add two parts then:
1. Validate input is 19 digits with reg expr and then parse and compare it